# What does this mean is that my agisoft PhotoScan does not understand Unsupported JPEG data precision 12 error?

Tags: agisoft-photoscan, historical-imagery

I want to see if anyone in here know what the problem is. When I load this imagery to my ERDAS it was able to read it and open it...

However, my agisoft PhotoScan would not load it since there is something it does not recognized .

Could anyone tell me what the problem is ?

Would anyone out here tell me what does this means ? When I add 4 photos to PhotoScan and I see that they are "No Image"

2018-09-28 13:48:03 libtiff error: Unsupported JPEG data precision 12;

2018-09-28 13:48:03 libtiff error: Unsupported JPEG data precision 12;

2018-09-28 13:48:03 libtiff error: Unsupported JPEG data precision 12;

2018-09-28 13:48:03 libtiff error: Unsupported JPEG data precision 12;

2018-09-28 13:48:07 libtiff error: Unsupported JPEG data precision 12;

2018-09-28 13:48:07 Error: Can't load image: C:/Bov_files/1938/BOV_11/19380724_BOV_11_104.tif

I want to know so i can understand and see if I could fix it ? My understand is that libtiff came from somewhere else ?

I will send them the imagery for them to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some investigated is that I found PhotoScan doesn't read 16 bit but the data compression doesn't matter so I opened ERDAS Imagine and use Rescale to change it back to unsigned 8 bit. It worked and was able to load them to PhotoScan .

Answer (score 3):

The JPEG compression scheme can be used in either 8 or 12 bit precision. It seems to me you have 12bit JPEG. Additional details see here: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/TIFF12BitJPEG